# run a docker mysql container and open it in one command

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to run and open a mysql Cli in docker just with one command . Something like this is not working:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 33060:3306 --name mydb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mysql mysql -p
```

I know I can connect to mysql *after* running my container this way

```
docker -it docker exec -it mydb mysql -p
```

but i want to do it in one liner.

Thanks

(Updated)*****

Seems that you can do it in version 8 calling MySQLsh at the end of the command. But unable to do it for previous versions

```
docker run --name=mk-mysql -p3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -it mysql/mysql-server:8.0.20 mysqlsh
```

Answer (score 2):

The database server and client are two separate programs.  A container only runs one program, so you can't run both the server and the client in the same container, both as the main process.  You could write a script that starts the container and then runs `mysql` to connect to it, but that's about the best you can do.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
docker run -d -p 33060:3306 --name mydb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mysql
exec mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=33060 --connect-timeout=60 --wait --password
```

If you're trying to do this to create a database or do other first-time initialization, you can bind-mount an initialization script into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and it will run as part of the database setup (only the very first time the database is started).

```sh
# Create the storage for the database
# (delete and recreate to rerun the init script)
docker volume create mysql-data

docker run \
  -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
  -v $PWD/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql \
  ... \
  mysql
```

If you're just trying to experiment with SQL commands, a serverless database like SQLite might fit your needs better.

Comment: You can do it using version 8: ‘ docker run --name=mk-mysql -p3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -it mysql/mysql-server:8.0.20 mysqlsh ’

Answer (score 0):

the `-p` parameter is for the ports to be published and should not be part of the `-it` interactive, that should be your error,

Have a read of the `docker run` command, in the docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: Using version 8 is possible but unable to call cli using version 5.7. (See updated question)